# Passing a string to a stored procedure from Python

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, stored-procedures

I'm trying to pass a string to a stored procedure written in Python using SQL Server 2017.

What I want to do is similar to:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS hello;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE hello (@my_text varchar(100))
AS  
BEGIN  
EXEC sp_execute_external_script @language = N'Python',   
@script = N'
print("Hello ", my_text)
'
END
GO

EXEC hello "world"
GO
```

This script fails with:

> NameError: name 'my_text' is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the SQL `@my_text` variable into the Python snippet.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE hello (@my_text varchar(100))
AS  
BEGIN  
DECLARE @s nvarchar(100)
SET @s = 'print("Hello ", "' + @my_text + '")'
EXEC sp_execute_external_script @language = N'Python',   
@script = @s
END
```